# Convert ISO8601 datetime to another datetime time zone

Tags: c++, date, datetime, c++17, iso8601

I need to convert a string of the form *ISO8601* (specifically, my strings are of the form **2023-07-04T00:00:00+04:00**) to the time zone of another string. That is, having a datetime string **2023-07-04T12:00:00+04:00** when converting it to the timezone of the string **2023-07-04T00:00:00+05:00** we should get the string of the form **2023-07-04T13:00:00+05:00** with the time stamp of the original string. I tried using the `Howard Hinnant / date` library, but I only found an option with conversion by specifying the IANA time zone, which is not present in this case. Is it possible to solve this problem with this library, or are there other means? C++17 is used.

Comment: Too bad you're stuck on C++17, as C++20 adds some nice [time zone utilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono#Time_zone).

Comment: What special methods does C++20 have for this? Judging from the documentation it also works with time zones using IANA, and in general is very similar to `Howard Hinnant / date`

Comment: The C++20 time zone utilities are essentially the Howard Hinnant / date library standardized (modulo change of namespace and other minor details).  If you are on C++20 and your vendor has implemented it, prefer the std::chrono version.  Otherwise use my lib as a fallback.  When it becomes practical, porting from my lib to C++20 will be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IANA has a full suite of timezones with names like `"Etc/GMT-4"` which match your `"+04:00".  Note the reversal of sign.  This is confusing but purposeful (IANA's decision, not mine).

[Here is a handy list of IANA time zone names.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

---

Here is sample code to extract a UTC timestamp and it's associated IANA Etc-name:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    istringstream in{"2023-07-04T00:00:00+04:00"};
    in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    sys_seconds tp;
    minutes offset;
    in >> parse("%FT%T%Ez", tp, offset);
    string tz_name = "Etc/GMT" + to_string(-offset/1h);
    cout << tp << '\n';
    cout << tz_name << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2023-07-03 20:00:00
Etc/GMT-4
```

Explanation:

The type of the time stamp is `sys_seconds` which is a seconds-precision [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) time stamp.  The type of the offset is `chrono::minutes`.  You can parse both of them out of the string by listing the offset after the time stamp in `parse`.

Because the type of the time stamp is a "sys type", the offset is applied to the parsed local time to result in a UTC time.  If a local time stamp is preferred instead, then change `sys_seconds` to `local_seconds`.

The number of hours in the `offset` can be extracted by dividing by 1 hour.  The result is a scalar which can be converted to a string (careful to apply the negation as shown).

The `tz_name` can then be further used as input to `locate_zone`, or in the construction of a `zoned_time`.

Disclaimer:  The code above is just a demo and is lacking in details including:

- Does not add `+` to the name for offsets west of the prime meridian.
- Does not deal with offsets that are not a multiple of hours.
- Does not demonstrate how to come up with the desired destination time zone name.
- Probably a few more things I haven't even thought about (time is tricky).

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. Then the formatting will be done by manually extracting the offset from datetime (For example we get -4 from +04:00 timezone) and adding it via some `.append()` to `Etc/GMT` to form similar IANA identifiers? Or are there more elegant ways than manually parsing strings and performing substitution?

Comment: Updated answer with example code.